# How to include two custom pages in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created EXE file using NSIS script.I have created custom page using following code,

```
page custom check

Function check
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My app" "UninstallString"
    IfFileExists $R0 +1 NotInstalled
        call nsDialogpage

    NotInstalled:
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogpage
     nsDialogs::Create 1018
     Pop $Dialog12
     ${If} $Dialog12 == error
         Abort
     ${EndIf}
     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
     Pop $Repair
     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
     Pop $Remove
     ${NSD_SetState} $Repair ${BST_CHECKED}
     ${NSD_GetState} $Repair $test
     --Do repair operation--
     ${NSD_OnClick} $Remove "Remove"
     nsDialogs::Show
     ${NSD_GetState} $Remove $RadioButton_State
     ${If} $RadioButton_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
         call Removed
     ${Else}
         Goto Done
     ${EndIf}
     Done:
FunctionEnd    

Function Remove
     nsDialogs::Create 1018
     Pop $Dialog12
     ${If} $Dialog12 == error
           Abort
     ${EndIf}
        --Do remove function--
      /* nsDialogs::Show*/
 FunctionEnd
```

If I run the above code it's not working.No code executed after show function.If i give show function before functionEnd it throws me Run time exception.Because inside Remove function also have one more show().

My Requirement is,

If the user clicks the remove radio button,moves to next page and do the un install process and page comes to end.I have tried this scenario using above code.but its working fine.

How to include two custom pages in nsis installer?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why delete the old question and basically ask the same thing again?

Comment: That question is not more clear.that's why i posted this

Comment: It would be even more clear if you posted code that people can compile, in this case that means at least the Page instructions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two custom pages in just the same way you are adding a custom page:

```
Page custom check 
Page custom Remove
```

As **Anders** said, everything you put after `nsDialogs::Show` doesn't get executed. You need to move this code to a new "leave" function:

```
Var RemoveRequested
Function RemoveCheck
    ${NSD_GetState} $Remove $RadioButton_State
    ${If} $RadioButton_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
        StrCpy $RemoveRequested "1"
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $RemoveRequested "0"
    ${EndIf}
FunctioEnd
```

You are saving the user selection in a global variable `$RemoveRequested`. Then, in the next custom page you can check this variable, and do anything you need, or just `Abort` and the second page will not be displayed.

And then, you need to modify your custom pages declaration:

```
Page custom check RemoveCheck
Page custom Remove
```

Now, `check` will be used to show the custom page, and when the user leaves the page (== clicks on "Next"), the function `RemoveCheck` will be executed.

Your Remove function should check the flag we just created:

```
Function Remove
    ${If} $RemoveRequested == "1"
        nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $Dialog12
        ${If} $Dialog12 == error
            Abort
        ${EndIf}
        --Do remove function--
        /* nsDialogs::Show*/
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks @Francisco.I'm also think same.but i cant Implemented.because i cant call nsDialogpage from the header file.I have called from another function (see code:nsDialogpage).so i cant call page custom nsDialogpage Mycustompage like this.give any idea?

Comment: Where is the FunctionEnd of check function?

Comment: sorry i forget to close that one.now I have included all the codes.

Comment: Thanks.works fine.but if the user select repair option that time also control goes to "Page custom Remove" and check the condition.I think this is not necessary.How to avoid that?

Comment: Use Abort to avoid showing the second page. For example, in your Remove function you can do this: `${If} $RemoveRequested == "0"
Abort
${EndIf}"

Answer (score 0):

After `nsDialogs::Show` the page is basically gone, do your work in the leave callback: `Page custom nsDialogpage dotheradiocheckinthisfunction`

Comment: can you please elaborate more? or where can i add your two lines code in my above source code?

Comment: It is just one line, you should already have part of it: "Page custom nsDialogpage"

Comment: Anders i have added the flow of code regarding repair and remove. give me any solution?